# Encrypt a datetime field in mysql server

Tags: mysql

I have 2 stored procedures `Encode`,`Decode` and i want to use this sp to convert my `datetime` column values (say `Dob`) to an encrypted date.***The problem is that the encrypted format is not in datetime(varbinary) and hence it cant be inserted into that field***.Changing the datatype or adding a new column doesn' favour me as my db is a huge one with lots of tables and sps.The steps I use presently is:

```
declare @datetime
set @datetime='01/02/2008 12:45 PM'
declare @secretDate varchar(400)
declare @date varchar(200)
set @date=(select Convert(varchar(200),@datetime,120)
EXEC @secretDate=dbo.Encode @date
set @date=(select Convert(varchar(200),@secretdate,120))
select Convert(varchar(200),convert(varbinary(MAX),@date)) as EncryptedDate
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do this change of the column definition in multiple steps.

1) Add a new encryptedDate column set to the encoded value.

2) Drop the existing date column from the table.

3) Rename the encryptedDate to existing date column name.

You may be able to do steps 2 + 3 in one command, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

> Any suggestion is appreciated!

This whole thing sounds like a bad idea. If the data is encrypted but the 'Decode' function is a stored procedure in the DB, then the data is effectively not encrypted. Doing this also prevents all data compares from working, which is a Bad Thing.

Why not just encode the data when you read it from the DB if you don't want to present it to users?

Answer (score 0):

Times, and particularly dates have a very unusual, non-linear structure. Even storing dates in structures intended for dates is difficult. If you need to store this data encrypted then don't try to store it in a date / datetime field.